# Optimizing game menus for different mobile screens

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile

So, the games I download from the google playstore follow a certain pattern: there is a background image at the menu, and there are a few buttons to click at;
I've checked those games at different devices and it seems like the background doesn't stretch or misfits, and the buttons fit themselves according to the smart device size(tablet/regular phone). here is what I tried:

https://jsfiddle.net/0fe2Lyjg/13/

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class "option1"><button>1</button></div>

    <div class "option2"><button>2</button></div>
    <div class "option2"><button>3</button></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.wrapper button{
  width: 33%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline;
}
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://www.uiupdates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/game-background.jpg")
}
```

here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

the picture pretty much describes it all; everything resizes to screen, and even if there was a logo drawn on the background it would appear at the same place. I am not sure about the actual design(colors textures etc) of the buttons but you can try whatever you want.

EDIT: using px with buttons dimensions will achieve bad results since one mobile screen might consider it too big/small. it should be dealt with %.

Comment: what is the question exactly? or do you want somebody to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
    html,body{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }

  html {

   background-image: url("http://www.uiupdates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/game-background.jpg");
   background-size: contain;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
  }

  .parent {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   overflow: auto;
  }

  .block {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: auto;
   display: inline-flex;
  }

  .center {
   margin: auto;
   width: 100%;
   height: 43%;
   padding: 10px;
   display: inline-flex;
  }
  button {
   width: 22%;
     height: 50%;
     margin-right: 20px;
     border: none;
     margin: auto;
  }

  @media (max-device-width: 887px){
  html{

   background-size: cover ;
  }

  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>test</title>
 </head>

<body>
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="block">
   <div class="center">
    <button>1</button>

    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the buttons overflow in regular mobile phones since you used px... 100px is too big for them, and probably too small for other devices. and the background repeats itself instead of fitting in exactly.